# Calling a method after fetch has been executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a fetch request that returns an array of strings.

```
fetch(linkFetch)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(arr => {
                that.setState({
                    images: arr
                });
            })
            .then(this.test());
```

on the last line you can see I try to call the method `test()` which is just trying to access the state that was set in the `fetch()` request.

```
test(){
    console.log(this.state.images[1]);
}
```

console logs 'undefined'

However, if I assign `test()` to a button or something so that I can manually call it works fine which leads me to believe that when I call `.then(this.test());` in the fetch request it is actually being called before the state is set.

How can I make sure it gets called after the state has been set in the fetch request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you pass to `then` needs to be a **function**.

You are calling `this.test` *immediately* (i.e. before the asynchronous function has resolved) and passing its return value (`undefined` as there is no `return` statement).

You already have an example of how to do this correctly **on the previous line** of your code.

```
fetch(linkFetch)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(arr => {
        that.setState({
            images: arr
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.test();
    });
```

Comment: @The_Lone_Devil — No, because that disconnects the function from the `this` context (and we can see that the test method uses `this`).

Comment: You might want to add that to the answer as it looks like my comment is what they thought they were doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

React provides a way to call a function after the setState has been executed. You can use the callback function as described in the react documentation 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

You can pass your desired function as a second argument to the setState call.

that.setState({
key:Val}, that.test);

Comment: @Quentin setState is an asynchronous call and hence the then block may get executed before React updates the state. I believe using the callback would ensure that the function is called only after setState